# Increase the value as soon as the condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I think this problem is quite easy but I can not find the correct function of pandas to achieve it or link in stackoverflow. I tried it with cumsum but did not succeeded.
My dataframe looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize data of lists.
data = {'time_id':[1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7],
        'param1':[20,3,4,21,19,8,9,18,6,4,2]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now i want to have a new column. And here it should always be increased after every 3rd time id. The output table should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract `1` and then use integer division by `3`, last add `1`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['time_id'].sub(1) // 3 + 1
print (df)
    time_id  param1  new_col
0         1      20        1
1         1       3        1
2         2       4        1
3         3      21        1
4         3      19        1
5         4       8        2
6         5       9        2
7         5      18        2
8         5       6        2
9         6       4        2
10        7       2        3
```

If not possible subtract `1`, e.g. because some another type of column, here timedeltas use:

```
df['time_id'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_id'], unit='s')
print (df)
           time_id  param1
0  0 days 00:00:01      20
1  0 days 00:00:01       3
2  0 days 00:00:02       4
3  0 days 00:00:03      21
4  0 days 00:00:03      19
5  0 days 00:00:04       8
6  0 days 00:00:05       9
7  0 days 00:00:05      18
8  0 days 00:00:05       6
9  0 days 00:00:06       4
10 0 days 00:00:07       2

df['new_col'] = pd.factorize(df['time_id'])[0] // 3 + 1
print (df)
           time_id  param1  new_col
0  0 days 00:00:01      20        1
1  0 days 00:00:01       3        1
2  0 days 00:00:02       4        1
3  0 days 00:00:03      21        1
4  0 days 00:00:03      19        1
5  0 days 00:00:04       8        2
6  0 days 00:00:05       9        2
7  0 days 00:00:05      18        2
8  0 days 00:00:05       6        2
9  0 days 00:00:06       4        2
10 0 days 00:00:07       2        3
```